# problem getting date time

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, object-model

I am using the CSOM in javascript. I have a list which contains 3 text types and 2 date types.
When I use:

```
  var listEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();
  var collection = listEnumerator.get_current();
  var linkTitle = collection.get_item('Start');
  alert(linkTitle);
```

For the text types it returns the correct information but when I input the name of the date type into `get_item` it doesn't even return an alert.

What is happening?

Comment: Perhaps you must call `moveNext()` first? In any case, open your browsers dev tool console (Usually F12), and check for errors

Comment: In my code there is move next is just didn't show it on here as didn't think it was relevant

Comment: Have you included those Date columns in your context.load()? context.load(listItems, "Include(Title, .....)");
Also you could add 'collection' variable into your console watch and see what all columns are being returned.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct internal name for that 'start' column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aveenav suggested see whether they are included in your Include().
Also verify whether your DEFAULT VIEW is having these columns included in list settings.